# Common abstraction between vector spaces and field extensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field

There seems to be a symmetry between properties of vector spaces and field extensions.

Let us create some small dictionary:

```
vector space over a field - field extension of a field
linear independence - algebraic independence
linear matroid - algebraic matroid
dimension - transcendence degree
```

What I want to know is: does there exist a common abstraction for both vector spaces and field extensions in which one can treat both of these in a unified way and derive the mentioned items of the dictionary (and hopefully much more) as special cases of the general framework?

Comment: Uhm... just "matroid"?

Comment: @darij grinberg This is of course true. But with the "(and hopefully much more)", I implied that I was hoping for something where much less trivial concepts for vector spaces such as "linear maps", "tensor products", ... map over.

Comment: Oh, what are tensor products for field extensions? Composita? I'm not sure that works (composita have the property $LL = L$, for example, whereas $V \otimes V$ is usually not $V$).

Comment: @darij grinberg I don't know whether something like this exists.